# What if the human body was subjected to separate levels of gravity each day?

Tags: science-fiction, gravity

Question: Would it be plausible for the human body to continuously experience regular changes in gravity? Like if someone were to exercise every morning at higher than normal gravity, above Earth norm, and then go back to normal gravity the rest of the day and night.

Would there be stress on the human body that makes this practice completely unfeasible and if it is feasible could it be kept up over a period of years? The effect, and purpose, of course being a stronger  body; it has also been stated by NASA that one might be able to accomplish a workout in less time.

Comment: It already does. During my waking hours it usually feels a 9.8m/s^2 acceleration towards my feet, when I sleep it usually feels a 9.8m/s^2 towards my back, when I sink in the tub it is considerably less towards my back and when I am swinging it feels no gravity at all. YMMV.

Comment: Different gravity areas would be useful in rehab, we use pools now to alleviate weight over certain joints during exercise. The exercises and training programs would have to be modified to suit the different gravity though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When talking about the effects of acceleration due to gravity, it suffices to forget all about the actual gravity mumbo-jumbo and simply consider the effects of prolonged acceleration on the human body.

To wit, anyone that has ridden any type of vehicle, an elevator, amusement park ride, has experienced acceleration on scales similar to the average acceleration due to gravity on Earth $(9.81 \text{ms}^{-2}$, or $1\text{g})$, and at a faster rate of cycle than you're talking about.

## Long term effects

We also know that astronauts can handle long periods of weightlessness while in orbit, known as microgravity. They  *are* still subject to about $0.9\text{g}$ of Earth gravity, but since they're in orbit, they're essentially in free-fall *around* the Earth. Now, by "they can handle it," I don't mean that microgravity is completely safe; the most common long-term side effects are loss of muscle and bone density. These can be mitigated with exercise.

However, those effects have been measured in *zero-g* environments; if  your gravity swings are less dramatic, these negative effects would almost certainly be less pronounced as well, although I do not know of any scientific source to give you hard numbers on that.

The effects would be less serious with a shorter duration as well, and probably nonexistent when *increasing* gravity. In other words, if your people just "crank up" the gravity for an hour or two per day during their workout, you'd probably see increased muscle mass and bone density, rather than decreased.

## Short term effects

Probably of greater concern in your scenario would be the short term effects of changes in gravity. Decreasing the gravity by a significant amount leads to a well-known condition colloquially referred to as "space sickness", or Space Adaptation Syndrome (SAS) to only the more rigidly formal audiences.

Space sickness causes nausea, vertigo (dizziness), headaches, and generally just feeling like crap. It affects about *half* of everyone who goes to space, and can take up to three days to go away. Although it's somewhat treatable with basic motion sickness medication, there would probably be people in your world who would never fully tolerate the shifts in gravity.

## Alternative solutions

Working out with more weight (which includes simply wearing weight belts and the like for cardio exercises) would have none of the above side effects, except for added stress on joints.

Comment: In response to the very last part. wearing a weight 'suit' of some kind will not accurately simulate full body resistance, at lest not completely. Perhaps most important of course, it's just not as dramatic.

Comment: @Split91 Thanks for accepting! Yes, you're right, the forces involved are not quite the same. But for the purposes of exercise, I don't need extra force on my pancreas, spleen and kidneys, I need extra force on my torso, arms, and legs so the muscles work harder. And, indeed, it certainly lacks some dramatic flair! I know nothing about the world you're creating, but who knows, maybe "weights are for wimps" who can't stomach the swings in local gravity? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the difference isn't too extreme, it could be kept up for a period of years by healthy adults, sure, but it wouldn't be safe for children, the elderly, and pregnant women, so no permanent settlement.

For those who could withstand the physical stress, physical exercise would be very important if you expect them to get much done during high-gravity periods.  They wouldn't adapt to short high-gravity cycles on their own, I don't think they would have enough exposure time.

Answer (score 1):

The human body will adapt to the greatest stressor within absolute genetic limits.  **So, visits to stronger gravity wells will just make a person stronger.  Shorter visits to weaker gravity wells shouldn't hurt at all.**

The human body is amazingly adaptive but only when stressed. Any stress less than a body's current maximum capacity will induce no physiological change. (How to go about inducing this kind of stress and how much stress to induce is a subject for a different Stack Exchange.  I prefer the Starting Strength method but that's just me.) It is only by stressing the body that we see adaptation.  We see this pattern in power lifting training when a trainee does not increase the weight (or duration of strain); they don't get any stronger or develop greater endurance.

As long as there is *some* gravity (so as to avoid the physical deterioration problems associated with zero-gravity) then extended stays in 0.25g to 1.0g shouldn't be a problem.  Limited stays in 1.1g to 1.25g shouldn't be too difficult though the higher the g loading, the shorter the stay.  Imagine an extended stay in 2.0g: Try to walk around with a barbell with your body weight draped over your shoulders for hours at a time.  You won't want to stay there very long.

*In short, there's no reason that the human body can't do brief stays in higher or lower gravity than 1g, especially if the stays in each gravity level are relatively short.*

Comment: What do you mean by "a body's maximum"? If you mean the high side of a current comfortable range, then you are *almost* correct, albeit bending the meaning of "maximum". If you mean that you must train to failure or not improve, though, you are *dangerously* wrong.

Comment: @TheNate I see what you mean.  I've clarified my answer to address your concern.

Comment: Definitely better, yeah.